# How to CAPITALIZE many character in string with iMacros Eval

Tags: eval, imacros

**How to replace many character with their CAPITALIZED form in a string/array in iMacros ( a to A , b to B etc)**

hopely i can get my problem with imacros.. i just wanna do :

tag 1 is abcd, and i want replace it with ABCD (capital).

for replace many character to one character usualy i use this code

" SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[():;?!': '' ']/g, '-');") "

its mean replace char / [ \ ( \ ) : ; ? !  to " - "

but how to replace per character like a to A, b to B (capital)

thanks for your attention..

Answer (score 1):

I'm barely starting to use iMacros, but i found your question looking to answer one of my own, and shortly afterwards I found this in the wiki:

Manipulate extraction

Transform extraction to uppercase characters:

```
    VERSION BUILD=7400919 RECORDER=FX
    TAB T=1
    URL GOTO=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html
    SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Early<SP>this<SP>year,* EXTRACT=TXT
    SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.toUpperCase()")
    PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

This is the page:
http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will need to capitalize only first letter of each word (for me it looks not possible to do with just regex \U$1):

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, m => m.toUpperCase());")
```